# Media queries. Which would be the standard?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Supposing we want to build a website with 4 different sizes. Which would be the standard procedure? Starting designing one size and modify the other 3 css attributes with media queries, or not putting any value in this attributes in the main size an creating 4 media-queries with these exclusives attributes?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you show a basic comparison of what you mean? What do you consider "main size"? There are two overarching methodologies: desktop first or mobile first. The direction you go depends on multiple factors.

Comment: If you're asking for opinions, this question is off topic here. We only do the kind of questions that have a singular correct answer, no questions that invoke discussions and (at worst; not saying this would happen here) flame wars.

Comment: That said, the usual approach is to start with un-media'd css rules and then follow up with the media queries for other screen sizes. And it's pretty standard to either assume a narrow screen by default and then work you way up to wide screens (mobile first) or the reverse (desktop first).

Comment: @JesseKernaghan I understand. So I suppose if we choice mobile first methodology we will be creating our main CSS with the smaller size and making media-queries for the other 3.

Comment: @MrLister Okay, understood! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current "best practice" is to make the mobile (lightest-weight) version the standard CSS without media queries, and add progressively heaver, more desktop-friendly CSS using media queries.  This is called [mobile-first responsive design](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/).

The thinking here is to get the low-end mobile processors to do as little work as possible to ingest their CSS, and let the big desktops worry about the complicated rule hierarchy and the heavy images that come with larger sizes.  But, this is just rule-of-thumb, it will work even if you do it the other way around.

Comment: Added link to html5rocks.

Comment: Completely understood! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After reading the question a few times, I think I'm getting the gist of the question. Either:

A) Start with one "screen size" style, and modify that for the 3 other versions ( which I would generally call major breakpoints ).

or

B) Keep each style for each screen in it's own media query, and have no "default" style.

You should go with option A, whether you are starting with mobile and working up to larger screens or vice versa. If you contain all of your styling in media queries you lose compatibility for older browsers ( that don't support media queries ) unneccessarily. You should also have common styles that wouldn't change based on media queries.

Comment: It was a bit confusing question but you got what I wanted to say. Thanks!